# Check Box In jsp page Using Jquery

Tags: jquery, jsp, checkbox

I am using checkboxes in my application and I have a problem that I haven't been able to solve despite my efforts.

```
function allChecked(status,set){
    alert(set);
    if(status)
        $('input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked','true');
    else
        $('input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked',''); 
    }
```

The above function selects or de-selects all checkboxes depending on the value of "status". "set" is a number that specifies how many checkboxes should be selected. So I want the code to select the checkboxes depending on value of "set". How do I do this?

Comment: Can you give us an example value for the "set" parameter?

Comment: Like I used select on page means in dropdown menu i gave value 10,15,25,100 depending on number of check box select  that is if i select 10 means ,ten check box select

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT :**

**For Function call you can use below code**

```
function allChecked(){
    if($('#selectall').attr('checked', this.checked))
        $(".case").attr("checked", "checked");
    else
       $(".case").removeAttr("checked"); 

    }
```

**Example** : http://jsfiddle.net/ipsjolly/wUgwz/7/

**You can also use ID instead of calling a function**

```
$(function(){

  // add multiple select / deselect functionality
  $("#selectall").click(function () {
      $('.case').attr('checked', this.checked);
  });

  // if all checkbox are selected, check the selectall checkbox
  // and viceversa
  $(".case").click(function(){

    if($(".case").length == $(".case:checked").length) {
        $("#selectall").attr("checked", "checked");
    } else {
        $("#selectall").removeAttr("checked");
    }

  });
});​
```

**Example** : http://jsfiddle.net/ipsjolly/wUgwz/8/

Source : http://viralpatel.net/blogs/multiple-checkbox-select-deselect-jquery-tutorial-example/

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to check or un-check the *first* N checkboxes (in the order in which they appear in the DOM), you can use the [slice](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) method to accomplish this:

```
function allChecked(status, set) {
    var checkboxes = $('input[type=checkbox]').slice(0, set);

    if (status) {
        checkboxes.attr('checked', 'checked');
    }
    else {
        checkboxes.removeAttr('checked');
    }
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/brianpeiris/Xs9Vc/

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
function allChecked(status,set){
alert(set);
if(status)
    $('input[type=checkbox]:lt('+set+')').attr('checked','true');
else
    $('input[type=checkbox]:lt('+set+')').attr('checked',''); 
}
```